# SQL not sure how to use select count as a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

table t1:

```
columns:
 id
 location
 calendar
 schdate
 schtype

select t1.id, t1.location, t1.calendar, min(t1.schdate), max(t1.schdate) 
from table t1 
group by t1.id, t1.location, t1.calendar
```

the above select produces the following results:

```
123   1   Base   8/7/2018    8/18/2018
123   1   Add    8/14/2018   8/17/2018
234   1   Base   8/8/2018    8/31/2018
234   1   Add    8/24/2018   8/24/2018
```

I'm trying to now add 2 more columns of results that are counts based on the schstyle where the other factors above are held constant.

something like

```
select t1.id, t1.location, t1.calendar, min(t1.schdate), max(t1.schdate),
(select count(t1.schdate) from table t1 where schtype=1),
(select count(t1.schdate) from table t1 where schtype=2)
from table t1
group by t1.id, t1.location, t1.calendar
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Your first query will not produce that result set. You will get a syntax error. Multiple errors, actually.

Comment: The `id` column should be the Primary Key, therefore the query will just reproduce the table. `Min` and `Max` values will be the same (`=schdate`), you don't have to use the functions and you don't have to use `GROUP BY`. For the two new columns, you could of course use something like *conditional expressionation*, or just use expressions like `2-schtype` and `schtype-1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `conditional aggregation`.  Also, in your example, you are missing your `group by` (assuming because this is just an example?).  Either way, something like this should work:

```
select t1.id, t1.location, t1.calendar, min(t1.schdate), max(t1.schdate),
    sum(case when schtype=1 then 1 else 0 end) as schtype1,
    sum(case when schtype=2 then 1 else 0 end) as schtype2
from table t1
group by t1.id, t1.location, t1.calendar
```

Comment: This looks like a perfect case for the `FILTER` clause, but it's seldom implemented.

Comment: @TheImpaler Isn't that only supported by `postgres`?  And yeah, it's a shame it's not more widely supported...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can try to use *condition aggregate function* instead of subquery.

```
select 
    t1.id, 
    t1.location, 
    t1.calendar, 
    min(t1.schdate),
    max(t1.schdate),
    sum(CASE WHEN schtype=1 THEN 1 END),
    sum(CASE WHEN schtype=2 THEN 1 END)
from table t1
GROUP BY    
    t1.id, 
    t1.location, 
    t1.calendar
```